# c# Retrieving a Certificate from an SSL stream shows different chain results vs other external tools

Tags: c#, ssl, https

I am working on a build a tool to test all my `SSL` certificates in my environment.

I am using the standard `SSLStream` implementation to connect to the remote servers, authenticate as a client and then use the `ssl.RemoteCertificate` method to retrieve the Cert.

The code works fine, I get the cert.  I build a chain from the cert, loop through the chain and enumerate all the certs in the chain.

I thought that I had gotten it working until I compared my output to `DigiCerts SSL Utility`.

I noticed that the chains that I got from it are different than the chain that I built through C#.

Digging a little more, I realized that, in my local store where the `C#` code is executed, there are multiple intermediate certs with the same subject name.

The only difference is there expiry.....

it appears that `C#` takes the newest cert with the oldest expiry....
4/29/2017

Where as the `DigiCert` tool displays the intermediate cert that is older with the expiry that is closer to expiring IE 4/29/2014

Is there a way to control how the chain is built?  (inside of `C#`)

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
{
    try
       {
         client.Connect("servername", 443);
          SslStream ssl = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificatValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);

          ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("servername");
          cert = new X509Certificate2(ssl.RemoteCertificate);

          PrintChain(cert);
        }
     catch(Exception ex)......
 }
private static void PrintChain(X509Certificate cert)
  {
       X509Chain ch = new X509Chain();

       ch.Build(cert);
       ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;

        foreach (X509ChainElement element in ch.ChainElements)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(element.Certificate.SerialNumber);
              // Go thru and print all my details and continue the loop
  }
```

I have also overridden the `ValidateServerCertificate` method and used the chain directly from that override instead of using the  `X509Cahin.Build();`

they print out the same.....

Thank you