# How is the X509Chain param built in the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback Delegate?

Tags: c#, .net

The `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` Delegate, shown below, is used to verify the remote Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate. The `certificate` parameter is the end entity server certificate returned by the remote server. What I'm not sure about is how the `chain` parameter is constructed. Is it built from the the list of certificates returned by the remote server (typically the server cert and intermediate CA certs) or does it go to the certificate local store and try to build a chain for the end entity server certificate returned in the `certificate` parameter?

```
// The following method is invoked by the RemoteCertificateValidationDelegate. 
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
      object sender,
      X509Certificate certificate,
      X509Chain chain,
      SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    ...      

}
```

*UPDATE*

I've got a suspicion it's using X509Chain.Build(server_cert), but would like to know what's really happening.

This person sees something similar: [c# Retrieving a Certificate from an SSL stream shows different chain results vs other external tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143845/c-sharp-retrieving-)
a-certificate-from-an-ssl-stream-shows-different-chain-result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is received from the server as part of the [TLS handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246):

> 7.4.2.  Server Certificate
>
> When this message will be sent:
>
> The server MUST send a Certificate message whenever the agreed-
> upon key exchange method uses certificates for authentication
> (this includes all key exchange methods defined in this document
> except DH_anon).  This message will always immediately follow the
> ServerHello message.
>
> Meaning of this message:
>
> This message conveys the server's certificate chain to the client.
>
> The certificate MUST be appropriate for the negotiated cipher
> suite's key exchange algorithm and any negotiated extensions.

> Structure of this message:
>
> ```
>  opaque ASN.1Cert<1..2^24-1>;
>
>  struct {
>      ASN.1Cert certificate_list<0..2^24-1>;
>  } Certificate;
> ```
>
> certificate_list
>
> This is a sequence (chain) of certificates.  The sender's
> certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following
> certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it.  Because
> certificate validation requires that root keys be distributed
> independently, the self-signed certificate that specifies the root
> certificate authority MAY be omitted from the chain, under the
> assumption that the remote end must already possess it in order to
> validate it in any case.

Well, according to [`X509Chain.BuildChain()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/security/system/security/cryptography/x509/x509chain.cs) it uses CAPI [`CertGetCertificateChain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376078(v=vs.85).aspx), which means is taken from local cert store, built up from a given cert. You can see how the validation callback is invoked in [`TransportSecurityHelpers.cs`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/TransportSecurityHelpers.cs). The chain is built in [`_SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_SecureChannel.cs):

```
chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = m_CheckCertRevocation? X509RevocationMode.Online : X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;
if (remoteCertificateStore != null)
   chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.AddRange(remoteCertificateStore);
if (!chain.Build(remoteCertificateEx)       // Build failed on handle or on policy
   && chain.ChainContext == IntPtr.Zero)   // Build failed to generate a valid handle
{
    throw new CryptographicException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

So it looks like the .Net takes *the* server cert from the SSL context and builds the chain using the CAPI chain building functions.

Comment: I appreciate the SSL protocol can receive multiple IA certs in addition to the server cert, but I'm not sure the X509Chain param is built using the IA certs returned by the server.For a start the chain I'm seeing contains the Trust Anchor which is definitely not sent from the server.

Comment: Yes, that confirms my suspicion. Thank you! Do you know if there is any way to get the actual list of any IA certs returned from the server?

Comment: As you can see .Net uses SCHANNEL under the covers, so you're bound to whatever [`QueryContextAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379340(v=vs.85).aspx) can return.

Comment: Do note that QCA remarks refer to 'intermediate certificates, if any'. It may worth check if this contains the server sent chain. If so it would mean that the .Net callback chain contains the server chain + any local chain (root CAs). I'm speculating.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for all your help on this Remus!